# How can I apply CSS formating to an XSL form input field

Tags: php, html, css, xml, xslt

So, I have this complicated little doo-dad of a web page that creates MADLIB type stories.  The stories are in XML format and look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <body>
       I remember going to sleep around <Num1 class="Number">9</Num1> O'clock.
       In my dream, I was laying on a <N1 class="Noun">table</N1> in a
       strange room with no <PN1 class="Plural Noun">windows</PN1> or doors.
  </body>
```

All the children of the "body" tag, such as "Num1," "N1," and "PN1" are processed into an HTML form using and XSL sheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">

<form method="post" action="Results.php" style="text-align:right;margin-top: 75px;margin-right:25%;">
  <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <label>
                <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>: 
                <input name="{name()}" type="text" />
            </label>
            <br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton"/>
  </xsl:for-each>  

</form>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From this, a form is created that displays a label based on the class of the child element, as well as an input box for the form data.  Something like:

Number:      _________
Noun:        _________
Plural Noun: _________
Submit

Lets say I enter 25 for "Number", Frog for "Noun", and Trees for "Plural Noun."

Once the form data is entered and submitted, the form data is processed through PHP to replace the child node strings in the original story.

```
<html>
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SFJPlaza.css"></head>
<body>

  <div id="story">

    <?php

      $file = $_POST[filepath];
      $open = fopen($file, 'r');
      $theData = fread($open, filesize($file));
      fclose($open);

      $doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($theData, LIBXML_NOERROR);
      if ($doc !== FALSE) {
          $text = ''; // used to accumulate output while walking XML tree
          foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
             if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) { // keep text nodes
                 $text .= $child->wholeText;
             } else if (array_key_exists($child->tagName, $_POST)) {
                 // replace nodes whose tag matches a POST variable
                 $text .= $_POST[$child->tagName];
             } else { // keep other nodes
                 $text .= $doc->saveXML($child);
             }
   }
//print $text . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Failed to parse XML\n";
}

        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $root = $xml->createElement("body");
        $xml->appendChild($root);

        $bodyText = $xml->createTextNode($text);
        $root->appendChild($bodyText);

        //$xml->formatOutput = true;
        print "<pre>".$xml->saveXML() ."</pre>";
    ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the story is displayed, it will read:

"I remember going to sleep around 25 O'clock.
           In my dream, I was laying on a Frog in a
           strange room with no Trees or doors."

All of this works great and fine and dandy. What I would like to do, though, is format the fields from the form data - 25, Frog, and Trees - separately.  This way I could add underlining, color, or bold styles to them to make them stand out from the rest of the story as the replaced words.

Anyone have any idea how I could do this?

Thanks in advance,
Mr. Mutant

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for-each select="*"` use `apply-templates select="*"` and then write templates for the different elements you have, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Num1">
  <label style="color: yellow">... </label>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The labels are for the form fields.  What I want to and add formatting to is the input data that is processed through PHP to display the final story.

Comment: As the question is tagged as XSLT, I assumed you need help with that part, sorry about that misunderstanding. So where you do `print "<pre>".$xml->saveXML() ."</pre>"` you want to apply CSS? As you simply write the XML into the HTML document I would start with CSS styling the elements e.g. inside your stylesheet you can define `Num1 { color: yellow; }`. Obviously a cleaner approach (which does not rely on styling of unknown XML elements in the middle of an HTML document) would be to define another XSLT stylesheet and have that transform and style the `$xml`, using `XSLTProcessor`.

Comment: Ahh!  Yes, I think I was making it too complicated.  If I just focus on the formating for the original XML file, it should come through regardless of what text is being entered or replaced. I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.